# Babel does not translate Map() when using Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a React App using Create-React-App. I've used the `Map()` datastructure included in ES6 in my app. However, in IE11 it does not work. Shouldn't Babel (under the hood of Create-React-App - I did not eject) take care of this?

If not, is there there any solution for that?

Comment: Babel need to be configured to make some class polyfills. Some of them are not posible (eg Proxy). Maybe this module can help https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map

Comment: I don't want to add another dependency if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others already mentioned, you are going to need a polyfill to add the functionality when it's not natively supported by the browser in question. Since you're already using Babel, the easiest way to do this is by using a Babel polyfill.

If you don't want to add another dependency, you can use the `Map` polyfill found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-map).

Comment: FYI, link is for Array.prototype.map, not Map.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Use `babel-polyfill` for cross-browser babel support:

```
npm install --save babel-polyfill
```

If you're using webpack/browserify then here's how you should incorporate the polyfill:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./app/js"]
};
```

If you're still unclear, read the documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Comment: This module supports Map Class?

Comment: I use Create-React-App. Webpack is included under the hood, but I cannot modify it without ejecting the app as mentioned before.